# Dynamically added EditText ignores theme

Tags: android

I have one EditText defined in xml and I want to add another one dynamically but the dynamically added EditText doesn't use the theme as EditText added using xml. The 2 EditTexts look differently, which isn't desired. See the image.

[image]

I tried it on API 28 and also on physical device Samsung S8+ API 26.

Any idea how to fix this? I don't see a reason why theme is ignored and as long as I know I can't apply theme to EditText?

Code:

```
public class TActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private LinearLayout Layout;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.t);

  Layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout);

  EditText editText = new EditText(this);
  editText.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
  editText.setEnabled(true);
  editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
  Layout.addView(editText);

 }
}

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ThisWorks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
</LinearLayout>

<activity android:name=".UI.TActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

Comment: What's the theme like?

Comment: @vilpe89 - Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar - I've added it also into the question - last line. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my app, I'm adding views dynamically by inflating an xml layout file, and there are no issues with themes. This is a piece of code that I use:

```
    View newView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.field, null);
    newView.setId(ViewIdGenerator.generateViewId()); //This is a custom method
    //that sets Id for a newly created view 
    //to find it later on for usage
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    newView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Because I create here a ConstraintLayout and you need an EditText, you should probably create a layout xml file with an EditText as its root, like the one below, and then inflate it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <EditText
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ThisWorks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine">
    </EditText>
```

I'm not sure if it works for you, but you might want to give it a try.